# cooking oven temperature

Tags: cake, temperature, oven

I have a murphy electric cake oven. it is a classic electric cake oven(not a modern one) In the recipe book it is mentioned to preheat it to 200 degree C for 10 mins. But it is not specified anywhere what should the temperature of the oven be while baking. My cake often gets overcooked/burnt if i keep a high temperature. or remains uncooked if i keep it low. Can anyone specify a temp. for baking a cake or a brownie please.

Comment: Ironically we had a previous question about what pasta instructions mean when they say bring to a boil then cook for X minutes, and in answering I said it was implied that you keep boiling, like oven instructions mean for you to heat then keep it heated. Maybe it's a more common confusion than I thought? http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/29939/1672

Answer (score 6):

The baking recipe idiom "preheat oven to X" implies to bake the item at that same temperature, unless the recipe specifies changing it.

200 C (390 F) is a little higher than most baked goods, but not out of the range of possibility.  more typical would be 180 C / 350 F.

Comment: I concur here; when baking from scratch, I usually use 180 degrees C.